# Sphere of slightly larger radius bounded by finite open cover

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I am given a n-sphere of radius $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, with the standard euclidean metric. If I also have a finite cover $\{B_{\epsilon_1}(p_1), \dots B_{\epsilon_m}(p_m) \}$ of my sphere, how can I construct a slightly larger sphere, of radius $R + \delta$ that is contained inside my cover?

Edit: We haven't done that continuous functions on compact sets have a compact image, and in particular, attain their minimum.

If we let (as Christian Blatter does) $U$ be the union of the $B_{\epsilon_i}(p_i)$, and $C = U^C$, then every point $p \in S$ has a non-zero distance to C. I want to argue that $\inf\limits_{p\in S}d(p, C) > 0$, where $d(p, C) = \inf\limits_{c\in C} d(p,c)$. However, I don't how to make that last step.

Answer (score 2):

If the $B_{\epsilon_i}(p_i)$ are meant to be closed balls the claim is *wrong*: The two balls $B_{\sqrt{2}}(0,0,\pm1)$cover $S^2$ but no point $(\rho,0,0)$ with $\rho>1$.

If the $B_{\epsilon_i}(p_i)$ are meant to be open you can argue as follows: Let $U$ be the union of these balls and $C:={\mathbb R}^{n+1}\setminus U$ their closed complement. As $S^2\subset U$ is compact the function $$f(x,y):=|x-y|>0\qquad(x\in S^2, \ y\in C)$$
assumes a  minimum $\delta>0$ on $S^2\times C$. It follows that $U$ contains an open spherical shell of thickness $2\delta$ with "soul" $S^2$.

Comment: Yes the $B_{\epsilon_i}(p_i)$ are meant to be open.

We haven't done continuous functions on compact sets have a compact image (to get that f actually attains its minimum).